# Set the clusterName in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to set the `clusterName` in `ElasticSearch` using the `restHighLevelClient` java library?

I didn't find a solution in the Elastic documentation.

RestHighLevelClient - version 6.2.4

Java - 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cluster name is configured in the `elasticsearch.yml` file (see doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html) )

All option in the restHighLevelClient is here to configure the client or use exposed `elasticsearch` API. Such low-level setting cant be changed at runtime.